# How do I add chaijs's assert in mocha's mocha.opts file?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I don't know if this is even possible. I know if we just use should.js library we can do the following in `mocha.opts` file

```
--require should
```

But since `chai` is a parent module and `assert` is sub-module of `chai`, how do I require it in `mocha.opts` file?

Or am I missing something really basic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK chai and mocha are not compatible in this way. It only works with `should` because `should` modifies the prototypes of the built-in objects, which some folks find acceptable for this particular use case but in general it is regarded as a bad practice to be avoided.

What you can do instead is write your own little wrapper module that does this:

```
global.assert = require('chai').assert;
```

And then in your `mocha.opts` you can do `--require global-chai-assert` and your tests will have access to chai's `assert` function as a global. I personally think this is an antipattern, but if you like it, that's how I'd do it.

Comment: I was afraid that there was some hack involved but this is better than nothing. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: It should be `global.assert` without the s.

Answer (score 0):

[Since chai v4.0.0](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/releases/tag/4.0.0) you can register assert/expect/should globals like this:

```
require('chai/register-assert');  // Using Assert style
require('chai/register-expect');  // Using Expect style
require('chai/register-should');  // Using Should style
```

So you can add it to your mocha.opts:

```
--require chai/register-should
```

There are some usage examples on the [chai's repo README](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/tree/master#usage).

Comment: Due to reasons beyond my understanding I had to write `mocha --require chai/register-expect.js` (with js-extension) for the cli command to work. I guess it has to do with node / cjs module syntax that has changed